# Get Function Property of a class using Expression

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression

I have a method which uses Expression to get Property name.

```
public static void SomeMethod<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
    var propertyName = property.Name;
    // Do something,
}
```

I am able to call this function for my classes like this.

```
SomeMethod(()=> SomePropertyName);
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I want to call this method for an class object which I am not aware of.

```
 void EventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var propertyInfo = sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
     SomeMethod(() => propertyInfo);  // Problem Here.
 }
```

Now problem here is that when this EventHandler calls SomeMethod, method name comes out to be propertyInfo instead of e.PropertyName (whatever this contains). sender can be of different types here and e.PropertyName can be of different type as well. I am looking for a generic solution which sends correct name inside SomeMethod.

Comment: I had misunderstood your question... Can you change the signature of SomeMethod? The problem is that calling it with the generic is very difficult, unless you call it through reflection. Does it use the TProperty?

Comment: No, that is some third party kind of stuff which I cannot change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void SomeMethod<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
    var propertyName = property.Name;
    // Do something,
}

public static void SomeMethod<TProperty>(object sender, PropertyInfo property)
{
    SomeMethod(Expression.Lambda<Func<TProperty>>(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(sender), property)));
}

public static MethodInfo someMethod = typeof(TypeContainingSomeMethod).GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(PropertyInfo) }, null);

static void EventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var propertyInfo = sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
    someMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType).Invoke(null, new[] { sender, propertyInfo });
}
```

Third time's the charm :-)

Quite complex... Have to use reflection because your method has a generic parameter, that clearly can't be solved at compile time.

Note that this is for properties... For fields some changes will be needed.

If you want, you can try "cheating" and call `SomeMethod<object>(...)`.. Then in EventHandler you can simply do this:

```
SomeMethod<object>(Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(sender), propertyInfo), typeof(object))));
```

Comment: Well, I am forced to used expression. So I need to pass it through expression, cannot send string to method.

Comment: What if I directly call "SomeMethod(Expression.Lambda<Func<TProperty>>(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(sender), property)));" in EventHandler and remove extra function?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez You can't. Your `SomeMethod` requires a defined generic type. `TProperty` must be defined somewhere, sadly you don't have it

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Clearly you can try cheating: call SomeMethod<object> and cast the Expression.Lambda.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Written the expression that "boxes" the value of the property. But note that then the other code won't see the name of the property, because the expression will be Convert(Property) instead of Property.

Comment: Ok, I am trying your first solution, I added SomeMethod with PropertyInfo in my class (making it public only, not static). I added MethodInfo as well (not static), but now public MethodInfo someMethod is giving me null. In binding flags I have removed static. But it is null. Why?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Because I've written `typeof(Program)`. Write the type that contains `SomeMethod`.

Comment: I have changed it to MyClass in which I am working. The original function with expression is in other project. MyClass is deriving from it MyClass : ThirdPartyClass (Third party has SomeMethod with Expression),

Comment: @FaisalHafeez To search for a public-non static method you have to search for: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance (Instance isn't predefined)

Comment: Non-static method requires a target.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35731/discussion-between-xanatos-and-faisal-hafeez)

Comment: There is difference between cheat method and other method, when use original method I get this in my expression method "{() => value(SomeClass).IsChecked}" but when I use cheat method I get this "{() => Convert(value(ProjectDatabaseRebuilderModel.ProjectModel.DiscoveryProject).IsChecked)}". Upon debugging I found out that cheat method gives UnaryExpression.